# Looking for young adult fantasy series

Tags: story-identification, books

There was a book I read in middle school and I cannot figure out what it is for the life of me. It's a fantasy book that is probably targeted at teenagers. I believe it was a series of books.

I hardly remember any details, but I know there is a section (I think in the first book) where the main character (or one of the main characters) is stuck in some suit of armor that makes him tread across the countryside. He becomes exhausted from walking but can't stop the suit.

I also remember a section where the main character and his sidekick are at a grand feast for some king, but he only offers them bread with some gravy on it.

EDIT:
This was in the early 2000s in the United States. The cover looked like colorful fractured glass. It was shorter than novel length. Maybe novella length.

Comment: When were you in middle school? Was this in the United States? Do you remember anything about the cover? Was it novel-length? Young reader novelette?

Comment: Middle school would have been in the early 2000s. Yes U.S. The cover was really colorful if I recall - it kind of looked like fractured glass with colors. I don't remember what image the glass created. It was no longer than a novella I would imagine.

Comment: Is it any of the works appearing in [this list](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnimatedArmor), by any chance?

Comment: @randal'thor The description of the armor in Voyage of the Shadowmoon feels very familiar, but when looking at the series, nothing else stands out. =\ Thanks for trying though!!